# Instagram API - How can I retrieve the list of people a user is following on Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I would like to know how I can retrieve the list of people a user is following on Instagram. This is given that this particular user is someone that I follow. So I have access to his/her photos and his followers on the Instagram app.

How can I use the Instagram API to do this? Is this legal to do?

Comment: re. legal - seeking alt. to manual scrape publicly available data is perfectly alright.

Comment: Vote for [this question on forum](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/451989888808340) to get an answer from the developers.

Comment: @activelearner check my  answer it may help you  out

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the following Instagram API Endpoint to get a list of people a user is following.

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Here's the complete documentation for that endpoint. <kbd>GET</kbd> [/users/user-id/follows](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows)

And here's a sample response from executing that endpoint.
[image]

Since this endpoint required a `user-id` (and not `user-name`), depending on how you've written your API client, you might have to make a call to the [/users/search](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search) endpoint with a username, and then get the user-id from the response and pass it on to the above `/users/user-id/follows` endpoint to get the list of followers.

[IANAL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=IANAL), but considering it's documented in their API, and looking at the terms of use, I don't see how this wouldn't be legal to do.

Comment: Yes, as of 1st of June 2016. Now you're only able to get the list of your own followers/followings.

Comment: Currently `follower_list` scope has status **(applications no longer accepted)**  In sandbox I tried this scope on my own user and I can get my followers. This probably would not work in production anymore right?

Comment: This api is used to get own followers/following list : `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Comment: That was when Instagram APi was not crippled. It started getting crippled by June 2016.

Comment: Neutered is a better word for what Lord Zuckerberg did to the API :)

Comment: @Mamta Could you provide the link to the API reference for that endpoint? I couldn't find anything. Probably also scraped by now?

Comment: This is entirely outdated.

Comment: This api no longer exits

Answer (score 93):

Further developed version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63056537/11865501

1. Open Instagram on your browser;
2. Login to Instagram;
3. Open your browser's console (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>);
4. Paste the code below;
5. Update the username in the first line;
6. RUN IT (Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```js
const username = "USER_NAME_HERE";

/**
 * Initialized like this so we can still run it from browsers, but also use typescript on a code editor for intellisense.
 */
let followers = [{ username: "", full_name: "" }];
let followings = [{ username: "", full_name: "" }];
let dontFollowMeBack = [{ username: "", full_name: "" }];
let iDontFollowBack = [{ username: "", full_name: "" }];

followers = [];
followings = [];
dontFollowMeBack = [];
iDontFollowBack = [];

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(`Process started! Give it a couple of seconds`);

    const userQueryRes = await fetch(
      `https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=${username}`
    );

    const userQueryJson = await userQueryRes.json();

    const userId = userQueryJson.users.map(u => u.user)
                                      .filter(
                                        u => u.username === username
                                       )[0].pk;

    let after = null;
    let has_next = true;

    while (has_next) {
      await fetch(
        `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a&variables=` +
          encodeURIComponent(
            JSON.stringify({
              id: userId,
              include_reel: true,
              fetch_mutual: true,
              first: 50,
              after: after,
            })
          )
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          has_next = res.data.user.edge_followed_by.page_info.has_next_page;
          after = res.data.user.edge_followed_by.page_info.end_cursor;
          followers = followers.concat(
            res.data.user.edge_followed_by.edges.map(({ node }) => {
              return {
                username: node.username,
                full_name: node.full_name,
              };
            })
          );
        });
    }

    console.log({ followers });

    after = null;
    has_next = true;

    while (has_next) {
      await fetch(
        `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=d04b0a864b4b54837c0d870b0e77e076&variables=` +
          encodeURIComponent(
            JSON.stringify({
              id: userId,
              include_reel: true,
              fetch_mutual: true,
              first: 50,
              after: after,
            })
          )
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          has_next = res.data.user.edge_follow.page_info.has_next_page;
          after = res.data.user.edge_follow.page_info.end_cursor;
          followings = followings.concat(
            res.data.user.edge_follow.edges.map(({ node }) => {
              return {
                username: node.username,
                full_name: node.full_name,
              };
            })
          );
        });
    }

    console.log({ followings });

    dontFollowMeBack = followings.filter((following) => {
      return !followers.find(
        (follower) => follower.username === following.username
      );
    });

    console.log({ dontFollowMeBack });

    iDontFollowBack = followers.filter((follower) => {
      return !followings.find(
        (following) => following.username === follower.username
      );
    });

    console.log({ iDontFollowBack });

    console.log(
      `Process is done: Type 'copy(followers)' or 'copy(followings)' or 'copy(dontFollowMeBack)' or 'copy(iDontFollowBack)' in the console and paste it into a text editor to take a look at it'`
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ err });
  }
})();
```

Comment: That is pretty good, can I ask what is the query_hash for? is any partcular value?

Comment: @Manza, the query_hash is coming from one of the answers I built on top of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62722236/11865501 . I didn't really investigate what it does, just went with it and built on top of that.

Comment: This is really good and still working in 01/2023

Comment: Any idea how to sort these lists in a chronological order?

Comment: I'll give that a shot later on @shAkur !

Comment: Please keep an update on this. I haven't found anything related to timestamps on the returned results

Comment: It's impossible to do that, since the IG API does not provide such data to public.

Comment: @shAkur For me, all the results come sorted chronologically descending.

Comment: LIne 111 is incorrect. It should be: -> `Process is done: Type 'copy(followers)' or 'copy(followings)' or 'copy(dontFollowMeBack)' or 'copy(iDontFollowBack)' in the console and paste it into a text editor to take a look at it'`

Comment: @Bruno , instead of using comments, you can try suggesting an edit directly on the answer

Comment: Still working on 5/12/2023

Comment: @JeanCosta Can this also be updated to see ghost followers? To see who of my followers that never have liked any of my content?

Comment: @AlexandraNicole , you can expand the script to do something along the lines. Create a `Set` to hold all your followers, fetch all your feed posts, get all the people who liked those posts and exclude them from the followers `Set`.  The users that remain on the `Set` will be the ones that never liked anything from you. You can see the API calls required to make that happen through the browser console.

Comment: Still working March 2024

Comment: I bet you can be banned for using this script

Answer (score 64):

Here's a way to get the list of people a user is following with just a browser and some copy-paste (A pure javascript solution based on Deep Seeker's answer):

1. Get the user's id  (In a browser, navigate to https://www.instagram.com/user_name/?__a=1 and look for response -> graphql -> user -> id [from Deep Seeker's answer])
2. Open another browser window
3. Open the browser console and paste this in it

```js
options = {
    userId: your_user_id,
    list: 1 //1 for following, 2 for followers
}
```

4. change to your user id and hit enter
5. paste this in the console and hit enter

```js
`https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a&variables=` + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
        "id": options.userId,
        "include_reel": true,
        "fetch_mutual": true,
        "first": 50
    }))
```

6. Navigate to the outputted link

(This sets up the headers for the http request. If you try to run the script on a page where this isn't open, it won't work.)

7. In the console for the page you just opened, paste this and hit enter

```js
let config = {
  followers: {
    hash: 'c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a',
    path: 'edge_followed_by'
  },
  following: {
    hash: 'd04b0a864b4b54837c0d870b0e77e076',
    path: 'edge_follow'
  }
};

var allUsers = [];

function getUsernames(data) {
    var userBatch = data.map(element => element.node.username);
    allUsers.push(...userBatch);
}

async function makeNextRequest(nextCurser, listConfig) {
    var params = {
        "id": options.userId,
        "include_reel": true,
        "fetch_mutual": true,
        "first": 50
    };
    if (nextCurser) {
        params.after = nextCurser;
    }
    var requestUrl = `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=` + listConfig.hash + `&variables=` + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(params));

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        var res = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

        var userData = res.data.user[listConfig.path].edges;
        getUsernames(userData);

        var curser = "";
        try {
            curser = res.data.user[listConfig.path].page_info.end_cursor;
        } catch {

        }
        var users = [];
        if (curser) {
            makeNextRequest(curser, listConfig);
        } else {
            var printString =""
            allUsers.forEach(item => printString = printString + item + "\n");
            console.log(printString);
        }
    }

    xhr.open("GET", requestUrl);
    xhr.send();
}

if (options.list === 1) {

    console.log('following');
    makeNextRequest("", config.following);
} else if (options.list === 2) {

    console.log('followers');
    makeNextRequest("", config.followers);
}
```

After a few seconds it should output the list of users your user is following.

Edit 3/12/2021

**Troubleshooting**

If you are getting an unfulfilled promise, double check these things

- Make sure you are logged in to Instagram ([user12857969's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60130481/9481858))
- Make sure you are not in incognito mode or otherwise preventing Instagram from verifying your login information.
- Make sure the account whose information you are trying to access is either public, or they have allowed you to follow them.

One way to check for an issue is the make sure the page you navigate to in step 6 has data. If it looks like the following, then you are either not logged in, the user is private and you do not have access to view their follows/followers, or your browser is not allowing cookies and Instagram cannot confirm your identity:

```html
{"data":{"user":{"edge_followed_by":{"count":196,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_mutual_followed_by":{"count":0,"edges":[]}}},"status":"ok"}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Is it browser-dependent? In Waterfox I get:
`Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: undefined }`

Comment: This was developed in chrome. I don't know much about waterfox, but in general I would try pasting in each javascript command in individually to see if any of them yield an unexpected result.

Comment: When I do this in chrome I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined
    at <anonymous>:58:1
(anonymous) @ VM69:58`

Comment: Same error message as @Ganlas. I don't think the `options` defined in step 3 is inherited in a new browser window from step 6 onwards.

Comment: I copied the `options` again in the console from Step 6. Running the script returned a Promise data response, and then a list of accounts I follow.

Comment: @Ganlas, the options variable is defined for the current browser tab only. If you switch tabs or windows, options will not exist, and you will need to recreate it.

Comment: Hi @CaitlinMorris thanks for sharing your solution! Is this solution still working for you? Because following the instructions I am ending up receiving a `Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}`

Comment: @user3191334 That is the initial return value, but after a few seconds you should get a list printed in the console. I tested it on ~300 usernames, so the time between when the promise is returned and when the list is printed should scale up if you have more. Are you working with an account that is following/followed by >1000 accounts? If so I would try it on a smaller account if you can.

Comment: I get the same undefined promise as @user3191334. The user does not have more than 100 follows. I didn't get anything printed to the console after that.

Comment: Cruz Nunez, I just added a troubleshooting bit at the end. Let me know if none of that works

Comment: Hey @CaitlinMorris, So I used your method and it worked fine for me.

My only problem is when an account has a lot of followers I can't find a way to get all followers list I only get about 500. Please if there is any way to get more than just 500 ( All followers if possible ) I would really appreciate your Help. Thank you.

Comment: Can confirm this still works as of early 2022 and is the only reliably - albeit clumsy - way to do this.

Comment: This is still working, and it timed out only after finding about 10.000 followers. I just see the final error in the console itself, but if I look at the network pane, I see all the responses. The issue is: I can copy them one by one (basically, a json with 50 users), but I don't see how I can export all responses at once, and this gets tedious pretty quickly. Any suggestions on how to get the network responses out?

Comment: This no longer appears to work.  I see `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query...`

Comment: For people who are still getting the 'options not defined error', The options parameter doesn't get carried over to the new tab that gets opened in step 6, you have to manually paste it in

Comment: This rate limits you after a while and you get blocked for some time. Be careful.

Comment: I'm getting `edges: []`. Is something changed the past 2 weeks? it worked for me before, but no more

Answer (score 63):

Shiva's answer doesn't apply anymore. The API call "*/users/{user-id}/follows*" is not supported by Instagram for some time (it was disabled in 2016).

For a while you were able to get only your own followers/followings with *"/users/self/follows"* endpoint, but Instagram disabled that feature in April 2018 (with the Cambridge Analytica issue). You can [read about it here](https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/04/facebook-instagram-api-shut-down/).

As far as I know (at this moment) there isn't a service available (official or unofficial) where you can get the followers/followings of a user (even your own).

Comment: This api is used to get own followers/following list : `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Comment: Is this API still valid? I am not able to see it in Instagram Documentation. 
 https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_self

Comment: No, this isn't available anymore. Instagram disabled the endpoint in the beginning of April as a result of the Cambridge Analytica case. You can read more about it in here: https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/ . I'll update my answer and describe the changes.

Comment: @MarkoSulamägi its little bit late but many app on play store is give analysis on follower analysis and they are able to get follower list how they are able to fetch that data which instagram is not providing

Comment: @ManthanPatel, I've been out of the loop with Instagram APIs for a while now so I'm not sure how they do it. It's possible they can access some of that data with the new Insights API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/insights .
Or they might be crawling the data from unofficial API (the one instagram.com or phone apps use). But the legal actions of crawling the unofficial APIs could get you in trouble, so I'd avoid that.

Comment: @MarkoSulamägi i try to reverse enginerring such apps and i found out they are using this(https://github.com/charlieAndroidDev/Instagram4Android) i am able to get the follwer list with this i didnt check how they are able to get but this is not official api

Comment: Yes, the library is crawling the API that the IG Android app is using. But this is probably illegal (or at least highly unethical) so I'd leave it at that and not discuss it further :)

Comment: There are many iOS apps shows User/Followers. I read the permission documentation on Instagram Developer docs. Followers request has been deprecated. But how App Store apps still shows followers? I do not understand. Anyone knows ?

Comment: @emresancaktar they are probably parsing the html

Answer (score 33):

I made my own way based on [Caitlin Morris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62722236/7496198) for fetching all folowers and followings on Instagram. Just copy this code, paste in browser console and wait for a few seconds.

You need to use browser console from [instagram.com](https://instagram.com) tab to make it works.

```
let username = 'USERNAME'
let followers = [], followings = []
try {
  let res = await fetch(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`)

  res = await res.json()
  let userId = res.graphql.user.id

  let after = null, has_next = true
  while (has_next) {
    await fetch(`https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a&variables=` + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
      id: userId,
      include_reel: true,
      fetch_mutual: true,
      first: 50,
      after: after
    }))).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
      has_next = res.data.user.edge_followed_by.page_info.has_next_page
      after = res.data.user.edge_followed_by.page_info.end_cursor
      followers = followers.concat(res.data.user.edge_followed_by.edges.map(({node}) => {
        return {
          username: node.username,
          full_name: node.full_name
        }
      }))
    })
  }
  console.log('Followers', followers)

  has_next = true
  after = null
  while (has_next) {
    await fetch(`https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=d04b0a864b4b54837c0d870b0e77e076&variables=` + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
      id: userId,
      include_reel: true,
      fetch_mutual: true,
      first: 50,
      after: after
    }))).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
      has_next = res.data.user.edge_follow.page_info.has_next_page
      after = res.data.user.edge_follow.page_info.end_cursor
      followings = followings.concat(res.data.user.edge_follow.edges.map(({node}) => {
        return {
          username: node.username,
          full_name: node.full_name
        }
      }))
    })
  }
  console.log('Followings', followings)
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Invalid username')
}
```

Comment: It gives an error - Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators

Comment: @RajathithanRajasekar I just run it again and it works fine. Make sure you open instagram.com and Inspect Element and paste this code to console. Or modify the code if you do it different way.

Comment: Hey @Chhaileng, thanks for your great code! Unfortunately this returns two empty lists. Is it still working for you? Thanks!

Comment: @user3191334 Yes bro, it is still working. You need to open instagram.com in the browser and open Developer Tool from that browser tab. Then, just paste this code into the console.

Comment: Ah sorry, you need to be logged in with a user ofc - I forgot. Thanks @Chhaileng great job!

Comment: This works as long as you're logged into ig. Very cool. Wondering if this is possible with rails

Comment: Is there any way to run this without opening instagram in browser, while maintaining status as authenticated user? I want to make a task to run this everyday.

Comment: can you tell me where this hash is coming from? and where can i read doc of this graphql API exactly? @Chhaileng . This works, thanks for help but I want to know if its ethical.

Comment: @minigeek you can browse the Instagram page on browser and inspect the Network activities, so you can see the API endpoints that it requests including the hash.

Comment: you can also use `window._sharedData.config.viewer.id` while being logged in to get the current userid if that is what you want.

Comment: it works in chromium. not firefox

Comment: Works perfectly, great code. You are awesome man!

Comment: If you try to do it with someone who has many followers (28k for my case), you will need to send a lot of requests. My account got suspended for breaking community guidelines on spam, but got restored immediately after challenging the decision. Nothing happened when fetching for ~500 followers (that sends around 10 requests)

Comment: Tweaked it with a couple more analytics (People that don't follow me back / People that I don't follow back), and also changed the approach for the user ID, given I was having issues on my end. Here's the new version: https://gist.github.com/Jeandcc/3c05d6104e94ded9884f4e39880d1be3

Answer (score 8):

I've been working on some Instagram extension for chrome last few days and I got this to workout:

First, you need to know that this can work if the user profile is public or you are logged in and you are following that user.

I am not sure why does it work like this, but probably some cookies are set when you log in that are checked on the backend while fetching private profiles.

Now I will share with you an ajax example but you can find other ones that suit you better if you are not using jquery.

Also, you can notice that we have two query_hash values for followers and followings and for other queries different ones.

```
let config = {
  followers: {
    hash: 'c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a',
    path: 'edge_followed_by'
  },
  followings: {
    hash: 'd04b0a864b4b54837c0d870b0e77e076',
    path: 'edge_follow'
  }
};
```

The user ID you can get from `https://www.instagram.com/user_name/?__a=1` as `response.graphql.user.id`

After is just response from first part of users that u are getting since the limit is 50 users per request:

```
let after = response.data.user[list].page_info.end_cursor

let data = {followers: [], followings: []};

function getFollows (user, list = 'followers', after = null) {
  $.get(`https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=${config[list].hash}&variables=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
    "id": user.id,
    "include_reel": true,
    "fetch_mutual": true,
    "first": 50,
    "after": after
  }))}`, function (response) {
    data[list].push(...response.data.user[config[list].path].edges);
    if (response.data.user[config[list].path].page_info.has_next_page) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        getFollows(user, list, response.data.user[config[list].path].page_info.end_cursor);
      }, 1000);
    } else if (list === 'followers') {
      getFollows(user, 'followings');
    } else {
      alert('DONE!');
      console.log(followers);
      console.log(followings);
    }
  });
}
```

You could probably use this off instagram website but I did not try, you would probably need some headers to match those from instagram page.

And if you need for those headers some additional data you could maybe find that within `window._sharedData` JSON that comes from backend with csrf token etc.

You can catch this by using:

```
let $script = JSON.parse(document.body.innerHTML.match(/<script type="text\/javascript">window\._sharedData = (.*)<\/script>/)[1].slice(0, -1));
```

Thats all from me!

Hope it helps you out!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works with website but there is a problem. That after variable is long string when I send new request with its new value api returns wrong json elements error. String is like this end_cursor :"QVFBRkJfQlVOYzdHeUp2cUxjWXRFcS1QTVFVTmVVSW1KbVlXQlhMTkZtLVdubmhiWTI2blFGVlUyeVZEMFM4V0JfMUMxb3NTblhQNDdka2pOcG10MGxQaQ==" Do you have solution for this?

Comment: Could you post some ss of error you get, I am using this daily and there is no error.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Phantombuster](https://phantombuster.com/api-store/7175/instagram-follower-collector). Instagram has set some rate limit, so you will have to use either multiple accounts or wait for 15 minutes for the next run.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get IG followers the best way in my oppinion is to login into IG on the web, and then take `x-ig-app-id` and `cookie` from request and then send GET Request to this endpoint:
[https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/friendships/{userId}/following/?count=20&max_id=12](https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/friendships/%7BuserId%7D/following/?count=20&max_id=12)

```
    {
        "users": [
            {
                "pk": 7385793727,
                "username": "nebitno",
                "full_name": "lela",
                "is_private": true,
                "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-sof1-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/144485752_4993231520748255_75575875121006268732_n.jpg?cb=9ad74b5e-c1c39920&_nc_ht=scontent-sof1-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=956dXauIBogAX_zfWPW&edm=ALB854YBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT_EGZmL2bx-zMSBQqxYKUjIaYWVVyBnPH9__Y9jAccF0w&oe=61DFADB1&_nc_sid=04cb80",
                "profile_pic_id": "2500168216063422867_7385792727",
                "is_verified": false,
                "follow_friction_type": 0,
                "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false,
                "has_highlight_reels": false,
                "account_badges": [],
                "latest_reel_media": 1641496960,
                "is_favorite": false
            },
      ...
]}
```

Comment: Do you have an updated version of that query? It does not work for me. I got deny cross origin

Comment: works for the `following` but not for the `followers` they have there `next_max_id` which is some weird hash and I have no idea how to use it

Comment: This Does Still work, I'm running tests with followers and I copied out the two headers mentioned and it works fine. Originally I left the gzip encoding accept in and so had to decompress that, but isnt needed if you dont send that header on the get.  One thing I did observe is my user id in the web vs work comes back from my token API does differ.  So I used the ID from the web and is working.

Answer (score 1):

The REST API of Instagram has been discontinued. But you can use GraphQL to get the desired data. Here you can find an overview: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api

Comment: I don't see any Graph API endpoint that can give you a list of *individual* followers. Only the total count.

Answer (score 1):

https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/friendships/2/following/

Where 2 is the user ID of interest. It returns a json of a list of user IDs, usernames, full names, profile pic URLs etc. It takes a GET parameter `?count=n` to limit the response.

Answer (score -1):

There is another way of doing this. Instapy provides us set of API for doing this.

Here is a simple code that can be used for this. We need to pass the **amount** of followers we need, in case we need all the followers list we need to pass **full** as the parameter value for the amount. The file containing the list will be stored locally.

Just make a simple pip install command.

```
pip install instapy
```

**Sample Code**

```
from instapy import InstaPy

user = <Username>
password = <password>
gecko_path = <geckodriver path>
#instapy uses this internally
session = InstaPy(username=user, password=password,geckodriver_path= gecko_path)
session.login()
followers = session.grab_followers(username=user,amount=40)
print(followers)
following = session.grab_following(username=user,amount=40)
print(following)
session.end()
```

Link to its documentation: https://instapy.org/

Comment: https://instapy.org/ is a broken domain now

Answer (score -1):

As per @Jackov GI answer if you log into the web version go to your profile and click 'following' you can see the URL api used. From the F12 debug window grab the Request headers value for cookie and x-ig-app-id.  Then you can fire a REST call get the results without hitting token server. The same mechanism can be used for the other API's To fully automate you might want to consider some other tool for loading the browser programatically and get your cookie.

One thing I did observe is that the user Id that comes back from my long token in FB setup seems to differ to my user id via the web.  However using the user Id from the web the folloing code works for me.  Tweek the params for differnt count items ect.

When you copy the cookie value remember to escape the quotes and back slashes.

Also this is super rough code lifted straight as I was testing not for code review!

```
var myfollowers = GetFollowers(<webuserid>).Result;

   public async Task<InstragramUserNode> GetFollowers(long userId)
{
    var getUserUrl = $"https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/friendships/{userId}/followers/?count=12&search_surface=follow_list_page";
    
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.instagram.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authority","i.instagram.com");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("path","/api/v1/friendships/{userId}/followers/?count=12&search_surface=follow_list_page");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("cookie","<your value>");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ig-app-id","<yourvalue>");
      
        var ff = await StreamWithNewtonsoftJson<Followers>(getUserUrl, client);
    }

    return new InstragramUserNode();
}

private static async Task<T> StreamWithNewtonsoftJson<T>(string uri, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
    using var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // throws if not 200-299

    if (httpResponse.Content != null && httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json")
    {
        var contentStream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(contentStream);
        using var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);

        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        
        try
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }
        catch(JsonReaderException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid JSON.");
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP Response was invalid and cannot be deserialised.");
    }

    return default;
}

public class Followers
{
    public List<User> users { get; set; }
    public bool big_list { get; set; }
    public int page_size { get; set; }
    public string next_max_id { get; set; }
    public bool has_more { get; set; }
    public bool should_limit_list_of_followers { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }


public class User
{
    public string pk { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public bool is_private { get; set; }
    public string pk_id { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic_id { get; set; }
    public bool is_verified { get; set; }
    public bool has_anonymous_profile_picture { get; set; }
    public bool has_highlight_reels { get; set; }
    public List<object> account_badges { get; set; }
    public int latest_reel_media { get; set; }
    public bool is_favorite { get; set; }
}
}
```