# Getting a users followed and followers list on Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

So I'm planning to make an analytics app based using Instagrams API. But i have a quick question since I'm sort of confused on this. On Instagrams documentation i see the following:

```
follower_list - to read the list of followers and followed-by users (applications no longer accepted)
```

So let's say the user using my app has authenticated.

Does the above mean that I can't access **their**, the users, followers and followed lists?

**Or** does this mean that I can't access the list of "followers" and "followed" other then the authenticated user? (ie the lists of another user that the authenticated user may be following)

Hopefully this makes sense.

I saw the following question posted, but i just want to be sure.
[Instagram API - How can I retrieve the list of people a user is following on Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407851/instagram-api-how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-people-a-user-is-following-on-ins)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of Oct 1 2017, Instagram is no longer approving `following_list` permission, so you cannot access authenticated or any user's followers/following. No other solution using official APIs