# Instagram API to get the following and followers lists

Tags: java, android, instagram-api

I want to create an Instagram app for Android. But I have more than one question.   I just want to get the following and followers lists

SO how can I create a callback url and how can I use securely?

Should I use Server-side (Explicit) Flow or Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication? [Instagram API](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint was removed by Instagram following the Cambridge Analyticia case.

[Instagram API - How can I retrieve the list of people a user is following on Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407851/instagram-api-how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-people-a-user-is-following-on-ins)