# Render Vue inside appended element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am making some chrome extension and it worked in jquery but because of some reactivity, I needed to switch to Vuejs.

Now if I bind Vue onto some random div, content from that div will be removed.

So I tried to append some element and then use that one, but seems like Vue can't find it.

```
  let el = document.createElement('div');
  el.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;top:0;left:0;';
  el.id = '#random12345';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  setTimeout(function () {
    const app = new Vue({
      el: "#random12345",
      data: {},
      render: h => h('some-component')
    });
  }, 3000);
```

For this I keep getting an error: **[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #random12345**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#random12345` selector means that it looks for an element with `id` attribute equal to `random12345`.

It should be:

```
el.id = 'random12345';
```

Comment: Glad it was that simple. Consider marking the answer as accepted if it solves the problem. Since it was a typo, the question will probably be closed.

Comment: I was searching for this so long that I needed to answer it myself :D
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60130481/12857969