# How to detect if a user followed a specific Instagram account?

Tags: php

I'm a newbie at website development, and this is part of my experimenting, but can anyone help me with how to make a PHP code that detects if a specific user already followed an Instagram account through a PHP website?

(Note: I also tried using IP Address but that affects the website if it changes connection)

Comment: Sounds like you would need to use the Instagram API for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instagram API - How can I retrieve the list of people a user is following on Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407851/instagram-api-how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-people-a-user-is-following-on-ins)

Comment: Getting a list if who followed and updates it in database maybe a solutions, but I still seeking for  one by one user who followed probably since estimated follower per daily would be 3-8 and keep decreasing