# How to detect if a user follows you on Instagram?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, httprequest, instagram

Products like [Loyalty lion](https://apps.shopify.com/loyaltylion?ot=aa9ba5d1-5ea6-4f92-9d50-4120e66f2842&surface_detail=lion&surface_inter_position=1&surface_intra_position=1&surface_type=search_ad) offer "reward points" when a user follows your Instagram account. I am trying to add the same functionality to my website but cannot for the life of me figure out how they do it. In Loyalty Lion you can click a "follow us on Instagram" button on your website, a small window opens, asks you to sign in to Instagram if you are not already, then imitates the follow automatically and closes the window. While this behavior is ideal, I thought I would try a simpler approach... but none of them seem to work.

My first thought was to ask a user to follow my account then click a verify button to receive points. This would trigger a function that checks if that specific user has my account in their list of follows. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407851/instagram-api-how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-people-a-user-is-following-on-ins) however, this solution is no longer viable (as of 2018).

My second through was to just record the follower count at the beginning of the process and check if it had increased when the user clicks confirms. I realize this is not very secure but it seemed like the most basic (and therefore most likely to be supported) method. I have tried three different implementations now to get my follower count and while some of them work on on my local machine, none work once deployed:

**Option 1**: Using axios.  worked the very first time I ran it but seems to be blocked on all subsequent attempts. If I simply paste the link into the browser I get readable JSON but the response to my HTTP request is gibberish.

```
const axios = require("axios").default;
exports.getInstagramFollowerCount = async (req, res) => {
  axios
    .get("https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1")
    .then((resp) => {
      return res.status(200).json({ count: resp.data.graphql.user.edge_followed_by.count  });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: JSON.stringify(err) });
    });
};
```

**Option 2**: using the instagram-followers package. This works locally but not when deployed to a firesbase server

```
const followers = require("instagram-followers");
exports.getInstagramFollowerCount = async (req, res) => {
  followers(username)
    .then((no) => {
      return res.status(200).json({ count: Number(no) });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err });
    });
};
```

**Option 3**: using the instagram-basic-data-scraper-with-username package. This works locally but not when deployed to a firesbase server

```
const instaObj = require("instagram-basic-data-scraper-with-username");
exports.getInstagramFollowerCount = async (req, res) => {
  instaObj
    .specificField(username, "followers")
    .then(resp => {
      return res.status(200).json({ count: Number(resp.data) });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err });
    });
};
```

Why is this incredibly rudimentary implementation not working when deployed? Does anybody know of a better way to confirm that a user has followed your account?

Comment: Instagram is one of the most annoying things to integrate with. Facebook is paranoid from data scraping and non-authorized use of their APIs. They literally spend millions of dollars to prevent people/companies from doing what you're trying to do. The very robust way of doing it is to go through their legal API channels. Most other solutions are very temporary and break very often.

Comment: I tried something sneaky a while ago-- use the user to initiate the request rather than my server. This makes sure that the requests are distributed and Instagram has harder time blocking it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I need it for the same reason (loyalty program)