# How to fetch Instagram followers via Jsoup (Android)

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

I need to fetch Instagram followers of a particular user via Jsoup.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/911nv.jpg)

So far I'm here, I found this code but it doesn't work

```
    private void getInstaFollowers() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String web_link = "https://www.instagram.com/zuck/";
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(web_link).get();
                String title = doc.getElementsByTag("parse").attr("title");
                Elements links = doc.select("-nal3");

                builder.append(title).append("\n");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    builder.append(link);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, builder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Fetching Instagram followers via Jsoup is a terrible idea!

JSoup is a (very) good HTML parser. But...

What happens when Instagram decides to change its HTML Structure and they change the names/ids or whatever else you are using to fetch data?

Then you have to research again, change the code, and that still wouldn't be long spanned since they may change it again!

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407851/instagram-api-how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-people-a-user-is-following-on-ins) and the proposed solutions to find another way. Unfortunately, Insta has no API (at least at the moment).