# What token do I need to retrieve user's instagram followers count? Can I somehow fetch user's instagram followers?

Tags: node.js, graphql, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get user's instagram followers by this endpoint:
https://www.instagram.com/spongebob/?__a=1

I tried to get data with instagram access token, but it isn't working. How can I retrieve this data in my app? what token do i need?
Also, is there any possibility to fetch user's following list? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407851/instagram-api-how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-people-a-user-is-following-on-ins), but I wasn't able to find any official documentation that it is impossible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

probably instagram changed the end point https://www.instagram.com/spongebob/?__a=1&__d=1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer helped. How did you know to change the query string to add `__d=1`? How do we keep tabs on these changes? (Instagram obviously doesn't want people scraping like this)