# Need Instagram Insights

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

I'm creating an app in which I need insights of instagram influencers like impressions,reach etc

I've used facebook graph api from which I can view basic data of an influencer like profile, posts etc but I need insights as well which I cannot get using graph api, so is there any other scrapper or tool from which I can get insights?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instagram API - How can I retrieve the list of people a user is following on Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407851/instagram-api-how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-people-a-user-is-following-on-ins)

Comment: Actually I need engagements, demographics and other analysis of an insta influencer

Comment: Have you tried this endpoint? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights If this doesn't return the data you're interested in, then it's not possible to get.